# WooCommerce mass product price updatation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a portal which sale jewelry products. The rate calculation is depend on Gold/silver market  rate  which update daily.
I have formula to calculate for example.
Product rate = Metal rate +making charges+tax

Metal rate change daily
I want implement functionality which allow me to update all product rates by updating metal rates.

is there any built-in feature , plugin available ?
Thank you.

Comment: If you want I can make a plugin for you. contact me @ rajkumar.gaur.91@gmail.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in function.php

First create a function for price update

```
<?php
function update_product_price(){
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $product;
    //get metal rate,making charge and tax
    $product_rate = $metal_rate + $making_charge + $tax;
    //update product price
    update_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_regular_price', (float)$product_rate);
    update_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_price', (float)$product_rate);

  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
}
```

Now all you need to do is set cron job in wordpress you can do it using action hook

```
add_action( 'is_add_every_day', 'update_product_price' );
```

Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'is_add_every_day' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_day', 'is_add_every_day' );
}
```

Add a new interval of day

```
// See http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/cron_schedules
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'is_add_every_day' );
function isa_add_every_three_minutes( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_day'] = array(
            'interval'  => 24*60*60,
            'display'   => __( 'Every day', 'textdomain' )
    );
    return $schedules;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Product import-export for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/) plugin allows you to bulk update product price effortlessly. To be precise, it gives provision to update a particular value of a product with a defined value. For example, to add a value 5 with the price of all products of your store, just specify “price+5” which adds 5 to the total price (via evaluation field functionality). The plugin is also equipped to provide automatic import and export of products using Cron.